# looking for recording of shacharit prayer - nusach chabad

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, hearing, nusach-ari

I have a blind relative who can no longer see properly and needs a clear and reasonably slow recording of the chabad shacharit prayer. Does anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: I have one made by my teacher for me

Comment: I think I can give you a copy

Comment: @hazoriz thanks but he passed away

Comment: Boruch Dayan emes

Comment: @hazoriz - I would like a copy. :)

Comment: @ezra how can I give it to you?

Comment: @hazoriz - why have you not sent it yet?

Comment: @ezra sorry I did not see your previous comment  until now , I am busy now, b"n I will send it on choilam moed , I made a copy of your email address (you can delete it if you want)

Comment: @ezra i just sent it

Comment: @hazoriz - Just saw it came in. Thank you so much! Such a mentch!

Answer (score 3):

This is a recording of all of weekday shaharit being read word-by-word by Rabbi Menachem Mendel Schneerson:
http://vimeo.com/18771198

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you ask Chabad. They may well have a recording, and if not, there may be someone willing to record it.