# Looking for a recording of Shacharit

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation

Is there an online (or downloadable) version of an Ashkenazic davening -- not chazzanut, just someone saying all the words to a weekday davening clearly and at a reasonable pace so someone davening can follow along?

The recording referenced in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38416/looking-for-recording-of-shacharit-prayer-nusach-chabad) question is not very clear, is more than a bit fast and I can't hear if the nusach is plain old Ashkenazic (Artscroll) or not.

I know that any generic version would have to be tweaked for variable specifics like the shir shel yom, or the inclusion (or exclusion) of mashiv haru'ach etc.

Comment: The recording in the question you linked is Nusach Chabad.

Comment: This is close to what you are looking for http://www.teach613.org/encyclopedia/prayer/daily-prayer/for-beginners-hebrew-reading-recordings/

Answer (score 1):

I own a CD from Chadish Media, "How to Pray the Complete Weekday Shacharit" but I can't find where you can get it online and [their website](http://www.chadishmedia.com/PRAY_IN_HEBREW.html) seems very old; but if you can get your hands on it that would be the best option. You could try emailing them or calling the number on the bottom of the page; I can't verify if those work though because I've never ordered through them.

(The disc follows Nusach Ashkenaz.)